# How to update a field even if it is not inside the build Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 variables that can be updated if I pressed a button. ***_tempQuan1*** is not getting updated (immediately) since it is not in the build Widget. On the other hand, ***_tempQuan2*** gets the updated for every button press. Is there a way so that I can get the ***_tempQuan1*** to work same as ***_tempQuan2***?

Note: I have tried to remove all other codes until I found out about the information above.

Edit: I have also tried to make it as a stateless widget and use Getx and make an observable variable but I still unable to do it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:awesome_dialog/awesome_dialog.dart';

class ShoppingWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => ShoppingState();
}

class ShoppingState extends State<ShoppingWidget> {
  int _tempQuan1 = 1;
  int _tempQuan2 = 1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  showBuyPopup() async {
    AwesomeDialog(
      context: context,
      dialogType: DialogType.NO_HEADER,
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 32.0,
                  height: 25.0,
                  child: Text(
                    _tempQuan1.toString(),
                  ),
                ),
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                  child: Material(
                    child: InkWell(
                      splashColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      onTap: () {
                        if (this.mounted) {
                          setState(() {
                            _tempQuan1++;
                          });
                        }
                        print('increase');
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: 35.0,
                        height: 32.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark.withOpacity(0.9),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                        ),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.add,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 18.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      buttonsTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
      showCloseIcon: false,
      btnCancelOnPress: () {},
      btnOkOnPress: () async {},
    )..show();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('PATH: item card widget build');

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                _tempQuan2.toString(),
              ),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                child: Material(
                  child: InkWell(
                    splashColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    onTap: () {
                      if (this.mounted) {
                        setState(() {
                          _tempQuan2++;
                        });
                      }
                      print('increase');
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: 35.0,
                      height: 32.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark.withOpacity(0.9),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                      ),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.add,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 18.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showBuyPopup();
              },
              child: Text(
                'Button',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to move the body of your dialog into it's own stateful widget.. ie something like

```
AwesomeDialog(
    context: context,
    body: MyAwesomeDialogBody(tempQuan: _tempQuan2),
).show()
```

And then have a stateful widget `MyAwesomeDialogBody` which basically does everything you had previously in the `body`.

You would also have to pass in some callback so the changes to `tempQuan` are communicated back to the parent widget..

Comment: Hi Herbert, it works. I have manage to retrieve also the tempQuan by using GetX.